# using (StateListDrawable) vs StateListDrawable

Tags: android, xamarin

I need to give a background color and pressed color dynamically in each row.
Which of two is the best approach? And which of two has better performance?

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
{
    var holder = viewHolder as adpCategoryPreviewViewHolder;

    using (StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable())
    {
    
        if (position % 2 == 0)
        {
            states.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#ffc27c")));
            states.AddState(new int[] { }, new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#FFFFFF")));
        }
        else
        {
            states.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#ffc27c")));
            states.AddState(new int[] { }, new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#bfddff")));
        }
        holder.layout.Background = (states);
    }
}
```

##VS

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
if (position % 2 == 0)
{
    states.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#ffc27c")));
    states.AddState(new int[] { }, new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#FFFFFF")));
}
else
{
    states.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#ffc27c")));
    states.AddState(new int[] { }, new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#bfddff")));
}
holder.layout.Background = (states);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPU Performance doesn't differ between the two examples. The only thing that differs is that the first example with the using pattern does, is to dispose the `StateListDrawable` managed instance when the code goes out of the scope of the `using`.

This will let the Android side get rid of its allocated memory, since it is a Managed Callable Wrapper, when it frees up the resources.

I would prefer the using pattern as it is more safe in terms of leaking memory. However, you won't be seeing any performance increase in terms of speed.